# Exception while calling Azure Function from Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have set up an Azure Powershell function with version 2.0. While executing the function from Azure Data Factory (ADF) getting below exception.

```
"errorCode": "2011",
    "message": "Could not load file or assembly 'CodeGenerator, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Azure Function1"
```

Function App Code

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

if ($name) {
    $status = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    $body = "Hello $name"
}
else {
    $status = [HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest
    $body = "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body."
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = $status
    Body = $body
})
```

I am a beginner to Azure Functions. Please help.

Comment: Would you mind including the script or a sample?

Comment: Jamie, do you mean the Azure Data Factory Code?

Comment: The function app code for ADF yes.

Comment: Your code is the out-of-box PowerShell function.  Can you run the function from the Portal?  All services -> Function App -> Your function app name -> Functions -> Name -> Run.  You should get status code 200 OK - Response "Hello Azure"

Comment: Yes, I am getting Hello Azure with status code 200 OK. But while I am using Azure Function as an activity in Azure Data Factory its throwing the error.

Comment: On the properties of the function (Edit Linked Service - Azure Function), do you have Auto Detect selected for "Connect via integration runtime", is the function app URL configured properly, ie "https://{your-function-name}.azurewebsites.net", and have you configured the function key which you get from *Host Keys* in the settings for your function?  If the answer to all these is yes, can you try switching the function runtime to version 1.0?

Comment: Could you please share some more details of your process(such as the screenshot of the configuration in your data factory and some other screenshots) ?

Comment: This issue was with integration runtime. I changed the runtime from self hosted to auto resolved and its working fine. Thanks all.

Comment: Hi @KanhuCharanSahu, I'm glad to hear that. Could you please put the solution to the answer area ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved , copy OP's comment , it will be helpful for others have similar issue :

> This issue was with integration runtime. I changed the runtime from
>   self hosted to auto resolved and its working fine.